# « En tous genres » ou « en tout genre » ?

Tags: pluriel, locutions

Quelle est la bonne version de cette expression ?

Doit-on écrire « en tous genres » ou bien « en tout genre » ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grevisse signale qu'avec l'expression *en tout genre* (*de tout genre*) l’adjectif *tout* est mis au singulier ou au pluriel, selon que *tout* est pris au sens distributif (c'est à dire qui s'applique à chacun en particulier) ou au sens collectif (plusieurs personnes ou plusieurs choses de la même espèce ). Mais, signale aussi Grevisse, le singulier tend à prévaloir. Et ça se comprend car parfois la différence entre sens distributif et sens collectif ne semble pas évidente à faire.

Exemples pris dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/genre) :

> - *Ces deux ruelles, ainsi disposées, contiennent une trentaine de maisons à six et sept étages, dont les cours intérieures, dont tous les appartements contiennent des magasins, des industries, des fabriques en tout genre* (Balzac, Cous. Pons,1847, p. 311).
> - *Un grand panier de babas, d'éclairs et gaufrettes! des « Saint-Honorés » en tous genres* (Céline, Mort à crédit,1936, p. 608).
> - *Les progrès de tous genres que le christianisme a fait faire à la société* (Chateaubr., Mém., t. 1, 1848, p. 632).
> - *La vie de Gaston − si féconde pourtant en triomphes de tout genre* (Du Bos, Journal,1925, p. 321).

Deux ngrams confirment la plus grande fréquence du singulier sur deux siècles avec une différence entre singulier et pluriel qui s'amenuise de plus en plus.

**[En tout genre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=en%20tout%20genre%2Cen%20tous%20genres&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cen%20tout%20genre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cen%20tous%20genres%3B%2Cc0)**

[image: en tout genre]

**[De tout genre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de%20tout%20genre%2Cde%20tous%20genres&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cde%20tout%20genre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20tous%20genres%3B%2Cc0)**
[image: de tout genre]

Il serait intéressant de voir si la même différence se manifeste dans les autres expressions avec lesquelles on peut employer indifféremment le singulier ou le pluriel, les expressions citées par Grevisse sont :

*toute affaire cessante, en tout cas, en toute chose, tout compte fait, de tout côté, de toute façon, de* (ou *en*) *tout genre, en tout lieu, de toute manière, à tout moment, en toute occasion, de toute part, en tout point, à tout point de vue, toute proportion gardée, à tout propos, de toute sorte, en tout sens, de* (ou *en) tout temps, à tout venant*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Les deux sont corrects. Tout dépend du sens de ta phrase.

**En tout genre** serait plutôt pour dire **n'importe quel genre**.
**En tous genres** serait plutôt pour dire **tous les genres**.